# SASS Theming on Angular

Tags: angular, sass

Following the question [How to implement switchable themes in scss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390664/how-to-implement-switchable-themes-in-scss) (especially the 2nd answer with ideas from [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1)), I tried to implement themes through SASS on my project.
But I cannot make it work.

---

I created [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gkexle?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) so that it is easier to explain and to see the problem:

On the main component, it is working as intended, switching theme in `app.component.html` (between **theme-one** and **theme-two**) changes the color of the `<p>`.

But on the sub-component (called `<my-component>`), the same rules are imported in the SASS file but it is not working there.
The underline rule (which is declared in the mixin) is seen, so it has been imported, but the colors are not changing when switching themes.
If I debug (in SASS using `@debug`), I can see that the colors are rightly fetched from the `$theme-map`, but it looks like they are not returned.

---

Is this a known issue linked to Angular encapsulation/scoping? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Isn't it just because you haven't wrapped the contents of your component in a div with class "theme-two" ?

Comment: @Alex The idea is to switch the theme only in the main tag so that all sub-tags are impacted

Comment: Angular uses style encapsulation by default so for all intents and purposes your child component isn't in that tag. You either need to give your child component ViewEncapsulation.None or apply that style in your styles.css rather than in your component css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [Angular's encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation).
As the themes are defined in `app.commponent`, the rules generated through the SASS mixin will only work in this file.

If you want the mixin throughout your project, you'll have to either change the encapsulation of your components, or use the ([deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)) selector `::ng-deep` which makes it global in your app:

```scss
@mixin themify($themes: $themes) {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {
    // ↓ here 
    ::ng-deep .theme-#{$theme} & {
      
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an [updated stacbklitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jiuqwj) with this modification.
You can see that the theme system is now working globally.